# Integrate Parse with Pusher

Tags: android, parse-platform, real-time, access-token, pusher

As per the [Pusher docs](https://pusher.com/docs/authenticating_users), for a client to subscribe to a private channel he needs to undergo some authorization process. Could someone guide me on how to achieve this using [Parse](https://www.parse.com/)? I already have integrated Facebook login with Parse for my android application. Im not too familiar with web development code so had difficulty in understand this

> HttpAuthorizer authorizer = new HttpAuthorizer(http://example.com/some_auth_endpoint);
>   PusherOptions options = new PusherOptions().setAuthorizer(authorizer);
>
> Pusher pusher = new Pusher( YOUR_APP_KEY, options );

Answer (score 0):

Somebody has written a Parse module that offers authentication functionality: https://github.com/kashif/pusher-parse

The auth example from the README is:

```
app.post('/authorise', function(req, res) {
  var socketId = req.body.socket_id;
  var channel = req.body.channel_name;
  var user_id = channel.split("-")[1];

  var user = Parse.Object.extend("User");
  var query = new Parse.Query(user);
  query.get(user_id, {
    success: function(userAgain) {
        var presenceData = {
          user_id: userAgain.id,
          user_info: {
            username: userAgain.get("username"),
            email: userAgain.get("email")
          }
        };
        var auth = pusher.authenticate( socketId, channel, presenceData );
        res.send(auth);
    },
    error: function(model, error) {
      res.status(403);
      res.send('Forbidden');
    }
  });
});
```